# In Angular, is it possible to validate required inside a patchValue?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular, is it possible to validate required inside a patchValue?  Below is my sample:

```
fltrFieldControl.patchValue({ value: [null, [Validators.required]] });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger validation after `patchValue` with `markAsTouched`

```js
fltrFieldControl.markAsTouched();
if(fltrFieldControl.invalid) {
}
```

Comment: How can I implement required validation?

Answer (score 1):

```
fltrFieldControl.setValue(value);
fltrFieldControl.updateValueAndValidity();
```

This will update the value as well as run all existing validators

Comment: How can I implement it?

Comment: @MaryReiaSundi he already give you the implementation, `fltrFieldControl` is one of your reactive angular fields, to get a reactive fieald instance you can also write 
`this.yourForm.get('name_of_field').setValue(value);  this.yourForm.get('name_of_field').updateValueAndValidity(value); 
`
it's almost the same as @Reza wrote

Answer (score -1):

So if you want to use your validator you could use a form for html and ts:

html:

```html
<form name="fltrFieldControl" [formGroup]="fltrFieldControl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="yourInputField" id="yourId"
               formControlName="yourInputField"/>
        <div *ngIf="fltrFieldControl.get('yourInputField')?.errors?.required">
        This field is required!
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

ts:

```js
fltrFieldControl = this.fb.group({
  yourInputField: [null, [Validators.required]]
});


//And if you call patchValue the validator also work!
updateYourForm(): void {
  fltrFieldControl.patchValue({
    yourInputField: "yourNewPatchedValue"
  });
}
```

Comment: I‘ve edited my code, so please try again. It would be also helpful, if you post more of your code.